# To have some assets as [something]

Tags: american-english, british-english

I'm going to send an introduction letter to an editor and just wanted to make sure I don't fail too early :-)
Is it correct/understandable to say **"I'm an employee of XYZ with some assets as blogger".**
I'm just trying to avoid some clichè statements like "I have experience as ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just about understandable but looks really strange. An **asset** is something you own or have the use of even if it's something intangible like a qualification or skill set, it certainly isn't what you do for a job. The computer or tablet you use in your work would be an asset as a blogger as would your ability to type but the work you do for XYZ is not a collection of assets, it's a set of responsibilities or tasks.

If you want to avoid 'experience' you could say "I am employed by XYZ with some responsibilities as a blogger" or, if blogging is the main aspect of your job, you could say "I am employed by XYZ as a blogger"